# How to get css sprite class in Compass in this manner?

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass

```
.offbeat {background-position: x y }
.active .offbeat {background-position: x y }
```

Becuase in active condition i want to chage the position of image.

active mean selected in my case

Answer (score 1):

For Styling simply add the active class -

```
<div class="offbeat active">Some Content</div>
```

If you are using jQuery -

```
$('.offbeat').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active')
});
```

And change the background position of the image -

```
.active{
  background-position: x y; /*New Position*/
}
```

Do not inherit active class with offbeat

Try adding -

```
.offbeat:active{...............}
```

Don't know about compass but this is how CSS works!

Comment: .active .offbeat and .offbeat:active are different. I have updated the question

Comment: My question is about compass only